# Proving a if a property holds for a dense set then it holds on the field that the set is a subset of.

Tags: analysis, continuity

I am currently studying for my analysis exam and have come across this question, I can't seem to grasp the idea of a "dense set" especially with the definition given in the question. When I read it, as they say epsilon can be any number grater than 0 then E can be all numbers can it not?. This notion of dense sets is completely new for me. Any hints would be appreciated.

> A set $E$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ is *dense* if for every $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and every $\epsilon$ $>$ $0$, E $\cap$ $(x-$$\epsilon$, $x+$$\epsilon$) $\neq$ $\emptyset$.
>   Show that: 1.) If $f$ :$\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$  is continuous and $f(x)=0$  for all $x$ in a dense set $E$, then $f(x)=0$  for all $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: An equivalent definition is that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is dense if every open set (equivalently every open interval) in $\mathbb{R}$ contains an element (equivalently infinitely many elements) of $E$.  This definition is almost trivially equivalent to the one given, but it is more immediately visual.  Yes, it's true that $\mathbb{R}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but a more interesting example is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (try proving this, if you'd like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to approach these problems is to prove this:

**Proposition** $\ $If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is dense then $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists (e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset E$ such that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e_n = x$.

To prove this, take $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and use the density of $E$ to find an $e_n \in (x-\frac{1}{n}, x+\frac{1}{n}) \cap E$. Then $(e_n) \subset E$ and

$$|e_n-x|<\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0 \ \ \ \textrm{as} \ \ \ n \rightarrow \infty.$$

Now suppose that $f(y) = 0 \quad \forall y \in E$ and that $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Take an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Select a sequence $(e_n) \subset E$ tending to $x$ as in the proposition above. Then

$$ f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(e_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}0 = 0, $$

where in the first equality I have used the continuity of $f$ and in the second I have used our assumption that $f(y) = 0 $ for all $y \in E$.

Answer (score 0):

If $E= \mathbb{R}$ there is nothing to prove. So we may assume that  $E \subsetneq \mathbb{R} $. Suppose  to the contrary that there is an  $a\in \mathbb{R} \setminus E$ such that $f(a)\not=0$. Let $\varepsilon=|f(a)|$ so there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|< \varepsilon$ whenever $|x-a|< \delta$ (because $f$ is continuous). Since $E$ is dense, there is a $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap E$ and then $|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(a)|< |f(a)|$, a contradiction.